# USB flash drive show error, not enough space

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, usb-drive

14.04 USB flash drive (32gb) was almost full, so I removed few files to free some space. But when I tried copy file into flash drive, it show error, not enough space. Although free space is enough so place file. What is the problem?

Comment: What format is the flash drive, how much free space does it have, and how big is the file? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Regular FAT32 format, 25.1gb used from 32gb, the file I tried copy is ~800Mb. `Error while copying "filename.avi". Error splicing file: No space left on device.` I see that all files I have removed from USB drive stay in Trash. But can't empty Trash for unknown reason, probably this is Ubuntu bug. When USB drive disconnected, Trash have no any files.

Comment: What happens when you try to empty the Trash?

Comment: Nothing, no errors.  Files remains in Trash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your files are still in the Trash. If you cannot empty this via the trash icon, you can try the following in a terminal:

```
rm -rf /media/<user>/<drive>/.Trash-1000
```

In the above, `<user>` is your user name and `<drive>` is the name of your USB memory stick. For example, if your user name is `minto` and the drive is named `MemoryStick`, you would run:

```
rm -rf /media/minto/MemoryStick/.Trash-1000
```

This should delete everything in the trash on the USB stick and give you back the free space.

Comment: I already tried remove via terminal, `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*`, not works.

Comment: He's telling you to delete the `.Trash-1000` folder `on the usb drive`. You do not need to root to do so.

Comment: `rm -rf /media/<user>/<drive>/.Trash-1000` yes, this works.  Why files was listed in Trash?

Comment: They were probably deleted from Nautilus with the regular delete command, which places them in the Trash to give you a chance to recover them. You can avoid this by either using `rm` to delete your files, or by using `Shift+Del` to bypass the Trash and delete your files permanently.

Comment: That's helpful info.